# DeleteFile which begin with substring

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to delete all the files which begin with sub string.

```
  CString Formatter = _T("C:\\logs\\test\\test_12-12-2018_1*.*");     
  DeleteFile(Formatter);
```

I intend to delete following files with above code

```
    C:\logs\test\test_12-12-2018_1_G1.txt
    C:\logs\test\test_12-12-2018_1_G2.txt
    C:\logs\test\test_12-12-2018_1_G3.txt
    C:\logs\test\test_12-12-2018_1_G4.txt
```

When I check error from GetLastError, I get ERROR_INVALID_NAME.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The [`DeleteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilea) function doesn't take a wildcard. You have to [find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) the files yourself.

Comment: You could do `system ("del C:\\logs\\test\\test_12-12-2018_1*.*");`

Comment: @PaulSanders a very ugly solution.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Why?

Comment: @PaulSanders because the proper way is to do it like the accepted answer suggests. If I continue your reasoning why not use `system("echo Hello world");` instead of `printf("Hello World");`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The point is, using `system` here offers significant simplification, unless one wants to trap and report errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DeleteFile` doesn't take wildcards. It looks like what you need is a `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`/`FindClose` loop to turn your wildcard into a list of full file names.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <pathcch.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "pathcch.lib")

// (In a function now)
WIN32_FIND_DATAW wfd;
WCHAR wszPattern[MAX_PATH];
HANDLE hFind;
INT nDeleted = 0;
PathCchCombine(wszPattern, MAX_PATH, L"C:\\Logs\\Test", L"test_12-12-2018_1*.*");
SetCurrentDirectoryW(L"C:\\Logs\\Test");

hFind = FindFirstFileW(wszPattern, &wfd);
if(hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // Handle error & exit
}
do
{
    DeleteFileW(wfd.cFileName);
    nDeleted++;
} 
while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &wfd));
FindClose(hFind);

wprintf(L"Deleted %d files.\n", nDeleted);
```

Note that `PathCchCombine`, `FindFirstFileW`, and `DeleteFileW` can all fail, and robust code would check their return values and handle failures appropriately. Also, if `FindNextFileW` returns 0 and the last error code is not `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES`, then it failed because of an actual error (not because there was nothing left to find), and that needs to be handled as well.

Also, if speed is a concern of yours (your example in your post about deleting four files in the same directory doesn't seem like it needs it), replace the line `hFind = FindFirstFileW(...)` with:

```
hFind = FindFirstFileExW(wszPattern, FindExInfoBasic, (LPVOID)&wfd, FindExSearchNameMatch, NULL, FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH);
```

Comment: however need `if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFind)` and better use `FindFirstFileExW` with `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` and `FindExInfoBasic`

Comment: @RbMm added `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` check, however, I don't think that the `-Ex` variant is needed for an operation this simple (OP shows intent to delete some files in a single directory, not further down the directory tree)

Comment: simply `FindFirstFileExW` with `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` and `FindExInfoBasic` very significant increase performance, unrelated are we need traverse directory tree

Comment: @RbMm Added that information to my post as an option (not in the main code), since I don't feel that the optimization would really benefit OP's simple example of four files

Answer (score 2):

Although you *can* search for the file names, and then call `DeleteFile` individually for each, my advice would be to use one of the Windows shell functions to do the job instead.

For example, you could use code something like this:

```
#define _WIN32_IE 0x500

#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

static char const *full_path(std::string const &p) {
    static char path[MAX_PATH+2] = {0};
    char *ignore;
    GetFullPathName(p.c_str(), sizeof(path), path, &ignore);
    return path;
}

static int shell_delete(std::string const &name) {
    SHFILEOPSTRUCT op = { 0 };

    op.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
    op.pFrom = full_path(name);
    op.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_SILENT | FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
    return !SHFileOperation(&op);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if ( argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: delete <filename> [filename ...]");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++)
        shell_delete(argv[i]);    
}
```

One obvious advantage to this is that you can pass the `FOF_ALLOWUNDO` flag (as I have in the code above), which moves the files to the recycle bin instead of removing it permanently. Of course, you can omit that flag if you want to the files nuked.

Depending on what you're doing, there are a few other flags that might be handy, such as `FOF_FILESONLY`, to delete only files, not directories that might match the wildcard you specify, and `FOF_NORECURSION` to have it not recurse into subdirectories at all.

Microsoft considers `SHFileOperation` obsolescent, and has (in Windows Vista, if memory serves) "replaced" it with [`IFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation). `IFileOperation` is a COM interface though, so unless you're using COM elsewhere in your code, chances are pretty good that using it will add a fair amount of extra work for (at least in this case) little or no real advantage. Especially you're already using COM, however, this might be worth considering.